# How to know Which versions of xslt and xsl-fo are uesd by Java program?

Tags: java, xslt

I have been using fop2.1 version to generate a PDF.
My question is where I can find which versions of xslt  and xsl-fo are being used by our program?

Comment: Do you use the default factory in JAXP? If so, In most oracle/openjdk JREs it's xalan 2.7.0. You can get this info by invoking the `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.Version#getVersion` through reflection. There is no way to get version info without touching implementation specific classes. If you need a particular version or another brand you have to ship it along your software or let end user supply it somehow.

Comment: To find out which XSLT version is supported by your processor you can use `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and what about xslfo version and can we able see xslfo formatted object before transformation to PDF .I am using saxon-he as xslt processor and supplied Saxon implemention for transformer. Please let me know if need more details.